# angular html5 mode allow file types with node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have an angular app in html5 mode, and a node.js express back-end using the following snippet I can redirect everything back to the route:

```
app.use('/*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

But because of this my ng-include will no longer work:

```
ng-include="'app/img/svg/star.svg'"
```

How can I allow certain file types that say end in '.svg' to still be loaded?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode.  Has a fully working example of how to correctly configure express rewrites for html5Mode.

Comment: Also, mind the order of your routes in the express app.

Comment: Nice one guys, cheers